# Find closest object in Java collection for a given value using Java8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to find a matching or a closest entry from a collection for a given timestamp value.

My collection is List of Object.. which contains `name`, `id`, `timestamp` etc..

```
String id;
long timestamp;
```

I want to first match on Id(you can have multiple) and then find the match for a given timestamp or return closest to it from collection. how can i do that?

```
myList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(Id))
                .min((f1,f2) -> Math.abs(f1.getTS() - timestamp) - Math.abs(f2.getTS() - timestamp))
                .findfirst().get();
```

its also having issue with long to int conversion too.

> error : type mismatch - cannot convert from long to int.

Comment: It seems that the problem here is probably the conversion that you mentioned. Can you provide the types of the variables and the error message?

Comment: Most probably, `f1.getTS() - timestamp` and `f2.getTS() - timestamp` are of type `long`. Rather than brutally casting them or the result of the subtraction to `int`, you should use `Long.compare(long,long)`

Answer (score 3):

What you are mixing up are two things, one that the Comparator return type mismatch as evident from the error you get. This could be resolved when you compare two `Long` values instead of performing a subtraction(`-`) for comparing.

```
.min((f1,f2) -> Long.compare(Math.abs(f1.getTS() - timestamp), Math.abs(f2.getTS() - timestamp)))
```

Then further it could be simplified to

```
.min(Comparator.comparingLong(f -> Math.abs(f.getTS() - timestamp)))
```

Another aspect is the mix up of `findFirst` with `min` since `min` itself returns an `Optional<T>` as the minimum element of the stream. Your solution can therefore be fixed with:

```
YourClass closest = myList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id))
        .min(Comparator.comparingLong(f -> Math.abs(f.getTS() - timestamp)))
        .orElse... // throw exception or choose default value
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
List<User> userList = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> user.getId().equals(ID))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(user -> Math.abs(TIME - user.getTime())))                                                            
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`userList` will be sorted according to nearest TIME (given timestamp) and do `get(0)`